# I want to print this! (+Blank, and use character)

Tags: java

i made ms excel example:
[image: i made ms excel example]

Anyway, I made code.
But this code is print only half. Why, why,!

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++) {
        for (int j = 1 ; j <= 9 ; j++) {
            if ( j < 10 - i ) {
                System.out.print(" "); 
            } else
                System.out.print("*");
        } System.out.println();
    }
```

Why printed only half.: (

Comment: The equation ` j < 10 - i` is not correct. But if I said what it should be, then I probably did your homework assignment for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is wrong, it should be:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
        if (j <= 5 - i || j >= 5 + i) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I didn't know I could write or, and in if,,!!  Thank you and happy new year :)